# How to change sequence type from int to bigint in Sql Server

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to change the type of an already created sequence from INT to BIGINT.
   I searched the types of alter possible, but the type I couldn't find how to change, for int, as initially declared, to bigint, as I require more values.
Regards,

Comment: not on my topic. I need only to alter the sequence only. If no other alternative, I'll just keep nextval into a variable, drop it, create it again and set the value recorded as the next value

Comment: For the last time...I use SEQUENCES, not IDENTITY! The current database structure and logic is with sequences not identities. I have 10 x 2 sequences (10 for scd tables and another 10 for scd2 tables) and it too complicated to switch to identities

Comment: Dropping and recreating is the only way out. You can not change the base type of its counter once it is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this,

1. Find the current_value of your sequence using the query below

   SELECT current_value FROM sys.sequences WHERE name = 'SequenceName' ;

   Lets assume your current_value of your sequence is 50
2. Drop and Recreate your Sequence Start with 50 (the value found in step-1)

   drop SEQUENCE SequenceName

   ```
   CREATE SEQUENCE SequenceName
       AS bigint   
       START WITH 50  
       INCREMENT BY 1  
       MINVALUE 50  
       MAXVALUE 9999999999....  
       CYCLE
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Just FYI, the data type of a sequence object cannot be altered. To change to an int data type, the owner must drop the sequence object and recreate the object with the correct data type. :)

src: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878572.aspx